# Finding smallest delta available for permutations of a set of numbers

Tags: combinatorics

Presume we have a set of 12 objects, lets say {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}. We must break this set into 4 smaller ones composed of three objects, so that the largest sum and smallest sum of these four sets is minimized. We must find this difference. In our example, {1,7,12},(3,8,9},{4,5,10},{2,6,11}. These four sets satisfy the problem since their sums are 20 and 19, meaning a delta of 1, our answer.

How can one solve this problem for any arbitrary 12 values?

Comment: Why 12 objects and 4 subsets? -- At least with these choices, the question is more suitable for Math.SE -- voted to migrate. Apart from this, I voted up "guest"'s answer, since in terms of mathematics it completely answers the question.

Comment: Also posted to stackoverflow, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081384/finding-smallest-delta-available-for-permutations-of-a-set-of-numbers ... without informing either site of the post to the other.

Comment: Also posted to http://3mr.me/finding-smallest-delta-available-for-permutations-of-a-set-of-numbers/ whatever that is. Heck, why not just hire a skywriter?

Answer (score 4):

Enumerate all partitions of your set into 4 sets of 3, and find the one that gives the optimal score.  If you care about speed instead of math, then there are probably better forums to post this question.

Comment: So that's a good, useful, mathematical answer? Just brute force through all 369600 solutions? I can hardly restrain myself not to downvote. I know the question is more suitable at math.stackexchange, but this answer is no better...

Comment: @beni What else do you expect?  A custom-written fast implementation for that special case?  Or am I supposed to decide how the OP wants the function to be parameterized as a function of N and then give the algorithm that has the best worst-case asymptotic performance for that parameterization?  If the OP wants that then they can give more information in their question.

Comment: On some previous incarnation of this problem, which I can't find now, I also suggested brute force. OP replied that 12-factorial things were too many to check. I don't know whether I succeeded in convincing OP that nowhere near that many were needed.